# Interprocess semaphores sometimes not working as expected

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86, semaphore

I have the following C code, where variables prefixed by **sm** are shared by two processes **proc1** and **proc2**. Therefore the semaphores are also shared. This code is called repeatedly. So if I say previous value, that means value of a previous iteration.

I notice in my program that **proc1** sometimes passes **sem_wait( sem_f2l )** without **proc2** executing **sem_post( sem_f2l )**. This I notice because **sm_value_proc1** and **sm_value_proc2** are supposed to be of same value in my program, which they are, as also confirmed by the printfs with **>>>**. However, the printf with **<<<** sometimes show different values. The difference is due to **proc1** printing the previous value of **sm_value_proc2** since **proc1** mysteriously doesn't sometimes wait for **sm_f2l** to be posted by **proc2**.

Any idea what is going wrong here?

```
// semaphores are initialized like this -> sem_init( sm_l2f, 1, 0 );
// Note that sm_l2f and sm_f2l are pointers to sem_t

// sm_condition is assigned here by proc1

if ( is_proc1 )
{
    sem_post( sm_l2f );
    // proc2_value should be updated by now here, but sometimes sem_wait
    //  passes without waiting for proc2 to post sm_f2l!
    sem_wait( sm_f2l );
    if ( sm_condition )
    {
        sm_value_proc1 = calc_value();
        printf( ">>> proc1 value = %u!\n", sm_value_proc1 );

        // If sem_wait and sem_post are working properly, printf will print
        //  the same value for sm_value_proc1 and sm_value_proc2 here, which it 
        //  sometimes doesn't, as the previous value of 
        //  sm_value_proc2 is printed.  
        printf( "<<< proc1 value = %u, proc2 value = %u, barrier_no = %d!\n",
                sm_value_proc1, sm_value_proc2, barrier_no[tid] );
    }
}
else // is proc2
{
    sem_wait( sm_l2f );
    if ( sm_condition )
    {
        sm_value_proc2 = calc_value();
        printf( ">>> proc2 value = %u!\n", sm_value_proc2 );
    }
    sem_post( sm_f2l );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is a copy/paste  error in the question (you are using copy/paste from the real code, right?), but it looks like you have a bug in proc2's handling:

```
// ....

else // is proc2
{
    sem_wait( sm_l2f );
    if ( sm_condition )
    {
        sm_value_proc1 = calc_value();  // <---  this should be assigning to
                                        //       sm_value_proc2
        printf( ">>> proc2 value = %u!\n", sm_value_proc2 );
    }
    sem_post( sm_f2l );
}
```

Then again, maybe it's a copy/paste error in the actual code?

Also - don't forget that `sem_wait()` can unblock due to a signal.

Comment: Thanks for pointing, its not the real code. I have now edited it.

Comment: Which kind of signal sem_wait can unblock from?

Comment: Any signal the process catches and handles.  Add a bit of code to check if `sem_wait()` return something other than zero.  Log the situation and/or retry the `sem_wait()` in that case.