# semaphore unexpectedly getting set

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86, semaphore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interprocess semaphores sometimes not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579672/interprocess-semaphores-sometimes-not-working-as-expected)

In my application, I notice that a semaphore of type **sem_t** sometimes become 1 from 0 without executing **sem_post**. How come? What can cause this? The semaphore is used for inter-process communication and you can look at the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579672/interprocess-semaphores-sometimes-not-working-as-expected).

Comment: wow, checking it I notice that @MichaelBurr already answered the same question, there. Would be nice if you could first integrate what people tell you before you ask a follow up question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you are linking to doesn't capture the return values from the `sem_t` calls. If you look in the manual you can see that e.g `sem_wait` can return prematurely, so-called spurious wakeups.

Always check the return codes of these functions. If the return is `-1` check `errno` for the corresponding error and decide if it is a transient error. If so, iterate.