# What to take care of in the presence of signals

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86, signals

I saw that semaphores in my application [were not always working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579672/interprocess-semaphores-sometimes-not-working-as-expected). Then I was told that this unexpected behavior can be caused when a signal interrupts the `sem_wait` call.

So, my question is what care needs to be taken by the programmer in the presence of signals. For `sem_wait`, we can check for the return values, but is this the same for all non-async safe functions? And what else we should keep in mind when expecting signals to interrupt our code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNIX signals is a can of worm, just to have said that.

There's 2 camps regarding syscalls and signals.

- SysV/Posix semantics: syscalls are interrupted by a signal, they return an error and sets errno to EINTR
- BSD semantics syscalls are auto restarted if a signal occurs (well, most of them are anyway, some are not, e.g. select/poll/sleep).

When using the signal(), the default is one of the two above, with BSD systems and Linux defaulting to BSD semantics, and everyone[citation needed..] else have the SysV semantics.
(On Linux, this depends on many things, e.g. compiling with -std=c99 gives SysV semantics, with -std=gnu99 gives BSD semantics. See e.g. http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Interrupted-Primitives.html)

When you install a signal handler with sigaction(), you get to chose which semantics with the SA_RESTART flags.

Basically:

- Don't use signals if you can help it.
- Use the BSD semantics if you can.
- On code that needs to be portable and handles signals, you need to wrap each and every system call in a loop that checks the call for failure, inspects errno for EINTR and perform the syscall again (or do something based on the caught signal ).
- library calls can use signals, even if your code don't.
- syscalls in general, with SysV/Posix semantics, will return -1 and set errno to EINTR. But read the documenation to learn what the error condition is.

EDIT: edited, as I mixed up BSD vs Sysv semantics.

Comment: So if SysV auto restarts a syscall, then why sem_wait is not getting restarted as it gives an error code sometimes?

Comment: @MetallicPriest Are you 100% sure it doesn't ? Anyway, I wish there was a list over exactly which syscalls that are not auto-restarted, even with sysv semantics. sem_wait might be one of them.

Comment: The default interrupt actions for any given system call should be documented in the system's manpage.  If you're on a Linux system, and didn't do anything abnormal, then your system calls should be restarted transparently after being interrupted by a signal.

Comment: Maybe its because I'm using semaphore for interprocess communication. For a process local semaphore, maybe what you guys are saying is correct.